# Black color behind the logo in splash screen

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, android-fragments, splash-screen

I want to show my logo in center of the screen until the flutter renders its first frame and for that i have the following code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

    <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
     <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Everything works fine when the device is in light mode i.e. the color behind the logo is white but as soon as i turn the dark theme on in my device then the logo is surrounded with the black screen. I want the background color to remain white regardless of the theme of device.

Comment: I've got the same problem, no solution yet